# Import class only if it's available (e.g. UIPopOverControllerDelegate only on >= 3.2)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got a class which is implementing the UIPopOverControllerDelegate:

```
#if ios_atleast_32
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIPopoverDelegate>
#elsif
@interface MyClass : UIViewController
#endif
```

Is it possible to make determine at runtime if the class is available and therefore should be used as delegate? The same for imports:

```
#if ios_4_available
#import "MyClassWhichIsUsingIos4Stuff.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the two above mentioned, it's no problem to import classes - but UIKit has to be weakly linked... that was the missing point in my case!

Answer (score 4):

You're building against the latest SDK so you can always `#import` new stuff and don't need any preprocessor macros there. The same is true for the protocol.

Just make sure that before using classes that are not available on all your supported OS versions you check whether that class exists or your app will crash:

```
Class someNewClass = NSClassFromString(@"SomeNewClass");
if (someNewClass) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

In newer versions of the SDK (don't ask me what exactly is the requirement) you can also do something like this:

```
if ([SomeNewClass class]) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: but my app crashes on iPhone 3.1 with the comment that UIPopOverController is not known; and I do not reach any code with UIPopOverController...

Comment: Please show me the code that crashes (or the error log). Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: According to apple engineers at WWDC the if ([SomeNewClass class]) pattern works all the way down to iOS 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply implement the protocol regardless of which iOS version will be used at runtime, and it will work fine.